# What is $E[N_s|N_t]$ for Poisson process with $s < t$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I'm a new learner of conditional expectation. I got stuck on this problem:
Suppose $\{N_t\}$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, then what is $E[N_s|N_t]$ for $s < t$?

My progress so far: 
Define $X_1 \sim Po(\lambda s)$ and $X_2 \sim Po(\lambda (t-s))$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Then 
$E[N_s|N_t]=E[X_1|X_1+X_2].$

I know $E[X_1|X_1+X_2]=\phi(X_1+X_2)$ for some Borel function $\phi(x)$. Question is how to find it here?
Another problem that has confused me quite long time is that what is $\sigma(X_1+X_2)$ for two independent RVs $X_1$ and $X_2$ here?

Comment: You can go to mass functions $Pr[A=a|A+B=k] = \frac{Pr[A+B=k|A=a]Pr[A=a]}{Pr[A+B=k]}$.  Or you can use the property that, conditioning on the number of Poisson events in an interval, their location distribution is independent and uniform over that interval. Can you work out the answer from there?

Comment: On your other question:  The simplest way to think of $E[N_s|N_t]$ is to find a function $\phi(k)$ such that $\phi(k) = E[N_s|N_t=k]$.  Then, the random variable $\phi(N_t)$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Michael Thanks so much for your hint, I'll have a try. Seems that, before I learned the formal definition of conditional expectation, I know how to calculate all kinds of conditional probability and conditional expectation. But after that, I know nothing about them :(

Comment: I know what you mean.  Sometimes formalism can make simple things hard. =)  The formalism is of course needed for the foundations of probability theory.  Like set theory and the Bertrand Russell stuff is needed for the foundations of arithmetic, but most people don't think of that when actually _doing_ arithmetic.

Comment: Informally: the best estimate for $\lambda$ given $N_t$ is $N_t/t$, hence $E(N_s|N_k)=s N_t/t$.